# Category Description

Tags: categories

Is there anyway to allow HTML into the 'Category Description' field or better add a WYSIWYG editor to this field? Any input would be a big help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know DevDemon's [Editor](http://www.devdemon.com/editor) adds WSYIWYG capabilities to the categories page. There may be other third party addon's that do this also, this is the first that comes to mind.